# What is suitable neural network architecture for the prediction of popularity of articles?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am a newbie in machine learning and also in neural networks. Currently I'm taking a course at coursera.org about neural networks, but I don't understand everything. I have a little problem with my thesis. I should use a neural network, but I don't know how to choose the right neural network architecture for my problem.

I have a lot of data from web portals (typically online editions of newspapers, magazines). There is information about articles for example, name, text of article and release of article. There are also large amounts of sequence data that capture behavior of users.

My goal is to predict the popularity of an article (number of readers or clicks on article by unique user). I want to make vectors from this data and feed my neural network with these vectors.

I have two questions:

**1. How do I create the right vector?**

**2. Which neural network architecture is best suited for this problem?**

Comment: There are some problematic points: The question for the `right` vector does not make sense. There's no right and wrong here, just `predictive` and `not very predictive`. Extracting good (=predictive) features is the essence of machine learning and highly depends on your problem. If there was a generic answer for this question, machine learning would be trivial task, wouldn't it? Your strategy here should be: Try features you think they could be predictive (e.g. number of words in the article) and see how well it works... The network really doesn't matter too much as long as it's not too simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are very broad questions. You'll need to identify smaller issues if you want more exact answers.

> How to create a right vector?

For text data, you usually use the [vector space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model). Best results are often obtained using [tf-idf weighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).

> Which neural network architecture is suitable for this problem?

This is very hard to say. I would start with a network with `k` input neurons (where `k` is the size of your vectors after applying tf-idf: you might also want to do some sort of feature selection to reduce the number of features. A good feature selection method is by [using the chi squared test](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/feature-selectionchi2-feature-selection-1.html).)

Then, a standard network layout is given by using a single hidden layer with number of neurons equal to the average between the number of input neurons and output neurons. Then it looks like you only need a single output neuron that will output how popular the article is going to be (this can be a [linear neuron](http://redwood.berkeley.edu/bruno/npb163/linear-neuron/linear-neuron-models.html) or a [sigmoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) neuron).

For the neurons in your hidden layer, you can also experiment with [linear and sigmoid neurons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neuron).

There are many other things you can try as well: weight decay, the momentum technique, networks with multiple layers, recurrent networks and so on. It's impossible to say what would work best for your given problem without a lot of experimentation.